# Python index value from list, return index value and list value

Tags: python, loops, indexing, spyder

I'm trying to use a list of specific codes to index any time one of those codes is used and then return the value of that code and the parameter name associated with it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

param_list = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Gordo/Documents/GraduateSchool/Research/GroundWaterML/parameter_cd_query.csv')

#def p_list():
#    return [param_list['p_cd'], param_list['param_nm']]

for item, value in param_list['p_cd'], param_list['parm_nm']:

    if item in ['p00010','p00020','p00025','p00058','p00059','p00090','p00095','p00191','p00300','p00301','p00400','p00405','p00410',
                   'p00450','p00452','p00453','p00602','p00607','p00608','p00613','p00618','p00631','p00660','p00666','p00671',
                   'p00681','p00900','p00904','p00905','p00915','p00925','p00930','p00931','p00932','p00935','p00940',
                   'p00945','p00950','p00955','p01000','p01005','p01010','p01020','p01025','p01030','p01035','p01040','p01046',
                   'p01049','p01060','p01065','p01080','p01085','p01090','p01106','p01130','p01145','p01155','p04035','p07000',
                   'p09511','p22703','p29801','p39086','p49933','p50624','p61028','p62636','p62639','p62642','p62645',
                   'p63041','p63162','p63790','p70300','p70301','p70303','p71846','p71851','p71856','p71865','p71870','p72015',
                   'p72016','p72019','p82081','p82082','p82085','p90095','p99832','p99833','p99834']:
       print (item, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have your own predefined codes and you're trying to see if items from a csv file matches any of your codes. If that's the case, you can get all the matches just by filtering the dataframe (since you're using pandas anyway).

```
import pandas as pd

param_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Gordo/Documents/GraduateSchool/Research/GroundWaterML/parameter_cd_query.csv')
my_codes = ['p00010','p00020','p00025','p00058','p00059','p00090','p00095','p00191','p00300','p00301','p00400','p00405','p00410',
               'p00450','p00452','p00453','p00602','p00607','p00608','p00613','p00618','p00631','p00660','p00666','p00671',
               'p00681','p00900','p00904','p00905','p00915','p00925','p00930','p00931','p00932','p00935','p00940',
               'p00945','p00950','p00955','p01000','p01005','p01010','p01020','p01025','p01030','p01035','p01040','p01046',
               'p01049','p01060','p01065','p01080','p01085','p01090','p01106','p01130','p01145','p01155','p04035','p07000',
               'p09511','p22703','p29801','p39086','p49933','p50624','p61028','p62636','p62639','p62642','p62645',
               'p63041','p63162','p63790','p70300','p70301','p70303','p71846','p71851','p71856','p71865','p71870','p72015',
               'p72016','p72019','p82081','p82082','p82085','p90095','p99832','p99833','p99834']

result = param_df[param_df.p_cd.isin(my_codes)]
```

`result` gives you all matches. If you just want an array with the first match, you can do:

```
result.loc[0].values
```